# Remove ImageView's excess padding

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I uploaded two images below, and some kind of excess padding is automatically created into the layout without me adding it.

**Image 1:**

When the image is in landscape orientation, the **excess padding** is at the **sides**.

[image]

**Image 2:**

When the image is in portrait orientation, the excess padding is located at **the top and bottom** of the **image**.

[image]

The excess padding occupies space on the layout, thus making it a problem.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@drawable/separator"
        android:dividerPadding="12dip"
        android:showDividers="middle"
         android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemItem"
        android:src="@drawable/content_picture"
        android:tag="image_item_grid_image"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:contentDescription="Desc"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPid"
            android:layout_below="@+id/itemItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textPid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textSellingPrice"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textSellingPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout >

</ScrollView >
```

---

**Java:** Programmatically place the image at the center.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            params.height = height / 2;
            params.width = width / 2;
            params.topMargin = 20;
            params.alignWithParent = true;
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

           mImageView.get().setLayoutParams(params);
            mImageView.get().setImageBitmap(bitmap.get());
```

Comment: can you please upload the image ?? or tell me whats the resolution of the image ?

Comment: Did you created an xml in the layout-land folder too ?

Comment: @RahulGupta, I am not sure what ur referring to.

Comment: You layout which you created for vertical orientation can appear not at the correct position when you rotate. For that you have to create layouts for landscape orientation as well. Read android documentation - Supporting Multiple Screens

Comment: did you see the extra padding? both the landscape and portrait has that, its eating the page.